# Plot the intensity of a continuous with geom_tile in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geospatial

I'm trying to plot a continuous variable on space.  I saw this example that gets the same result that I need:

```
library("MASS")
library("ggplot2")
library(reshape2) 

DB<-melt(volcano)
ggplot(DB, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +geom_tile()
```

[image]

So I did with my data:

```
library(repmis)
url<-"https://www.dropbox.com/s/4m5qk32wjgrjq40/dato.RDATA"
source_data(url)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dato,aes(y=variable,x=y,fill=value))+geom_tile()
```

[image]

That's wonderful. But my "x" and "y" are kilometers distance (east and north) from a point in space. I transformed these in latitude and longitude. But now my plot doesn't work!

```
ggplot(dato,aes(y=lat,x=long,fill=value))+geom_tile()
```

[image]

I don't understand why. Anyway plotting my data like points the result is very similar:

```
ggplot(dato,aes(y=lat,x=long,fill=value))+geom_point()
ggplot(dato,aes(y=variable,x=y,fill=value))+geom_point()
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html ,
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/scale_gradient2.html

Comment: I think it's because the latitude and longitude points are not spaced evenly and hence don't form a grid. If distance is spaced evenly then the coordinates can't be and vice versa. If you plot the latitude and longitude points you'll find that they are very slightly tilted. You'll probably have to do some interpolation to get it to work.

Comment: I find the interpolation a little complicated. Is there an alternative to geom_tile to have the same result?

Comment: Sorry just saw this comment now but looks like you got a good solution :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can cheat a bit and use `geom_point` with a square shape:

```
#devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis")
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
library(grid)

gg <- ggplot(dato)
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=long, y=lat, color=value), shape=15, size=5)
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + scale_color_viridis(na.value="#FFFFFF00")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

I did not project the lat/long pairs and just used `coord_equal`. You should use a proper projection for the region being mapped.

And, now you have me curious as to what those hot spots are around Milan :-)

```
gmap <- get_map(location=c(9.051062, 45.38804, 9.277473, 45.53438),
                 source="stamen", maptype="toner", crop=TRUE)
gg <- ggmap(gmap)
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=dato, aes(x=long, y=lat, color=value), shape=15, size=5, alpha=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + scale_color_viridis(na.value="#FFFFFF00")
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Really inspiring. You made my day.